# "Unable to translate Unicode character \\uD83C" error when returning JSON from asp.net POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, unicode, json.net

I develop a web api in MVC project. I return a JToken object in my post method. Usually my api works correctly but some times in specific data I get this error:

```
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": null,
  "InnerException": {
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Unable to translate Unicode character \\uD83C 
   at index 411 to specified code page."
```

This is my post method

```
public JToken Post([FromBody]Classes.Search search)
    {

        Classes.ReturnSearch returnSearch = new Classes.ReturnSearch();
        try
        {
            string con = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(con);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SP_Searchi", cn);
            sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@word", search.word));

            sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@num", search.num));
            DataSet d = new DataSet();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(d);
            DataTable table = d.Tables[0];

            foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                string result=row[1].ToString();

                returnSearch.search_items.Add(new Classes.SearchItem(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(),search.word));
            }
            returnSearch.status = "Success";


            return JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnSearch));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            returnSearch.status = "Failed";
            returnSearch.search_items = null;
            ValuesController.Log("Error in Search: "+e.Message);
            return JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnSearch));
        }


    }
```

What's problem?!

Comment: [`U+D83C` is not a valid unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d83c/index.htm).  How did this character appear in your returned object in the first place?

Comment: I went ahead and modified your original title *Overlapping recycle view after rotation* to be more reflective of the problem.  Feel free to change back if that was undesirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that [`U+D83C` is not a valid unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d83c/index.htm) that nevertheless has somehow made its way into one of the strings inside your `returnSearch` object.  Then subsequently the asp.net-mvc framework throws an exception trying to encode such a character to utf-8.

What you need to do is to determine how this character got into your `returnSearch` results and fix that underlying problem.  Since you are already manually converting your returned results to a `JObject`, to make the debugging easier you could test-encode all your strings to utf-8 and throw an exception if there is a problem, using the following converter:

```
public class EncodingValidatingStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    readonly Encoding encoding;

    public EncodingValidatingStringConverter()
        : this(Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding.UTF8.CodePage, new EncoderReplacementFallback("?"), new DecoderExceptionFallback()))
    {
    }

    public EncodingValidatingStringConverter(Encoding encoding)
    {
        if (encoding == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.encoding = encoding;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var s = (string)value;
        var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(s);
        var sFixed = encoding.GetString(bytes);

        writer.WriteValue(sFixed);
    }
}
```

Then modify your `Post()` method to catch and log an `EncoderFallbackException` and handle the problem as seems advisable.  For instance, the following version of your method replaces invalid characters with a `?` character after logging:

```
        try
        {
            // Fill in the returnSearch

            // Convert to JObject and return
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Converters = new[] { new EncodingValidatingStringConverter(Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding.UTF8.CodePage, new EncoderExceptionFallback(), new DecoderExceptionFallback())) },
            };
            return JObject.FromObject(returnSearch, JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings));
        }
        catch (EncoderFallbackException ex)
        {
            // Log the encoding error for debugging:
            ValuesController.Log("Encoding exception:\n" + ex.ToString());
            // You could log the search parameters or entire search_items list as well if desired.

            // Return whatever seems most advisable, e.g. replacing the bad character with a fallback if preferred.
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Converters = new[] { new EncodingValidatingStringConverter(Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding.UTF8.CodePage, new EncoderReplacementFallback("?"), new DecoderExceptionFallback())) },
            };
            return JObject.FromObject(returnSearch, JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            returnSearch.status = "Failed";
            returnSearch.search_items = null;
            ValuesController.Log("Error in Search: " + ex.Message);
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Converters = new[] { new EncodingValidatingStringConverter(Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding.UTF8.CodePage, new EncoderReplacementFallback("?"), new DecoderExceptionFallback())) },
            };
            return JObject.FromObject(returnSearch, JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings));
        }
```

Note that test-encoding each string will have negative performance implications, so once you have fixed the underlying problem you should remove this workaround.

Incidentally, rather than `JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnSearch))` you can do [`JObject.FromObject(returnSearch)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_FromObject.htm). This method writes directly to a `JToken` hierarchy without the intermediate string representation and thus should have better performance.

Answer (score 5):

This is an emoji modifer. You're probably seeing it after parsing an entered emoji (which can be split into a number of \u#### instances).